# How to merge object proprieties by id

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects:

```
const a = [{
  name: 'Mauricio',
  house: '2'
}, {
  name: 'Joao',
  street: 'holiday',
}, {
  name: 'Mauricio',
  apartment: 'two'
}];
```

How can I merge proprieties by `name`?

For example:

```
const b = [{
      name: 'Mauricio',
      house: '2',
      apartment: 'two'
    }, {
      name: 'Joao',
      street: 'holiday',
    }];
```

Comment: What hae you tried so far?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Let me update the post.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `reduce()` group and merge by name and create an object and then use `Object.values` to get the array back

```js
const a = [{
  name: 'Mauricio',
  house: '2'
}, {
  name: 'Joao',
  street: 'holiday',
}, {
  name: 'Mauricio',
  apartment: 'two'
}];

const res = Object.values(a.reduce((ac, a) => {
  if(!ac[a.name]){
    ac[a.name] = {};
  }
  ac[a.name] = {...ac[a.name], ...a};
  return ac;
}, {}));
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to for loop instead of reduce

```js
var a = [{
  name: 'Mauricio',
  house: '2'
}, {
  name: 'Joao',
  street: 'holiday',
}, {
  name: 'Mauricio',
  apartment: 'two'
}];

var indexByKey = {};
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
  var index = indexByKey.hasOwnProperty(a[i].name)? indexByKey[a[i].name]:-1;
  if(index >= 0)
  {
    Object.assign(a[index], a[i]);
    a.splice(i, 1);
    i--;
    continue;
  }
  
  indexByKey[a[i].name] = i;
}

console.log(a);
```